# Braintree - Google Pay button does not display

Tags: javascript, braintree, google-pay

i just cut & paste this code on a html file that I called payg.html : https://jsfiddle.net/f1am0dr7/

I paste the "jsfiddel html section" at the beginning of the page.

```
<div id="container"></div>
<script async
  src="https://pay.google.com/gp/p/js/pay.js"
  onload="onGooglePayLoaded()"></script>
```

and the "jsfiddle javascript section"  below and between

```
<script> & </script>
```

-

```
/**
 * Define the version of the Google Pay API referenced when creating your
 * configuration
 *
 * @see {@link https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/reference/request-objects#PaymentDataRequest|apiVersion in PaymentDataRequest}
 */
const baseRequest = {
  apiVersion: 2,
  apiVersionMinor: 0
};

/**
 * Card networks supported by your site and your gateway
 *
 * @see {@link https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/reference/request-objects#CardParameters|CardParameters}
 * @todo confirm card networks supported by your site and gateway
 */
const allowedCardNetworks = ["AMEX", "DISCOVER", "INTERAC", "JCB", "MASTERCARD", "VISA"];

/**
 * Card authentication methods supported by your site and your gateway
 *
 * @see {@link https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/reference/request-objects#CardParameters|CardParameters}
 * @todo confirm your processor supports Android device tokens for your
 * supported card networks
 */
const allowedCardAuthMethods = ["PAN_ONLY", "CRYPTOGRAM_3DS"];

/**
 * Identify your gateway and your site's gateway merchant identifier
 *
 * The Google Pay API response will return an encrypted payment method capable
 * of being charged by a supported gateway after payer authorization
 *
 * @todo check with your gateway on the parameters to pass
 * @see {@link https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/reference/request-objects#gateway|PaymentMethodTokenizationSpecification}
 */
const tokenizationSpecification = {
  type: 'PAYMENT_GATEWAY',
  parameters: {
    'gateway': 'example',
    'gatewayMerchantId': 'exampleGatewayMerchantId'
  }
};

/**
 * Describe your site's support for the CARD payment method and its required
 * fields
 *
 * @see {@link https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/reference/request-objects#CardParameters|CardParameters}
 */
const baseCardPaymentMethod = {
  type: 'CARD',
  parameters: {
    allowedAuthMethods: allowedCardAuthMethods,
    allowedCardNetworks: allowedCardNetworks
  }
};

/**
 * Describe your site's support for the CARD payment method including optional
 * fields
 *
 * @see {@link https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/reference/request-objects#CardParameters|CardParameters}
 */
const cardPaymentMethod = Object.assign(
  {},
  baseCardPaymentMethod,
  {
    tokenizationSpecification: tokenizationSpecification
  }
);

/**
 * An initialized google.payments.api.PaymentsClient object or null if not yet set
 *
 * @see {@link getGooglePaymentsClient}
 */
let paymentsClient = null;

/**
 * Configure your site's support for payment methods supported by the Google Pay
 * API.
 *
 * Each member of allowedPaymentMethods should contain only the required fields,
 * allowing reuse of this base request when determining a viewer's ability
 * to pay and later requesting a supported payment method
 *
 * @returns {object} Google Pay API version, payment methods supported by the site
 */
function getGoogleIsReadyToPayRequest() {
  return Object.assign(
      {},
      baseRequest,
      {
        allowedPaymentMethods: [baseCardPaymentMethod]
      }
  );
}

/**
 * Configure support for the Google Pay API
 *
 * @see {@link https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/reference/request-objects#PaymentDataRequest|PaymentDataRequest}
 * @returns {object} PaymentDataRequest fields
 */
function getGooglePaymentDataRequest() {
  const paymentDataRequest = Object.assign({}, baseRequest);
  paymentDataRequest.allowedPaymentMethods = [cardPaymentMethod];
  paymentDataRequest.transactionInfo = getGoogleTransactionInfo();
  paymentDataRequest.merchantInfo = {
    // @todo a merchant ID is available for a production environment after approval by Google
    // See {@link https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/guides/test-and-deploy/integration-checklist|Integration checklist}
    // merchantId: '01234567890123456789',
    merchantName: 'Example Merchant'
  };
  return paymentDataRequest;
}

/**
 * Return an active PaymentsClient or initialize
 *
 * @see {@link https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/reference/client#PaymentsClient|PaymentsClient constructor}
 * @returns {google.payments.api.PaymentsClient} Google Pay API client
 */
function getGooglePaymentsClient() {
  if ( paymentsClient === null ) {
    paymentsClient = new google.payments.api.PaymentsClient({environment: 'TEST'});
  }
  return paymentsClient;
}

/**
 * Initialize Google PaymentsClient after Google-hosted JavaScript has loaded
 *
 * Display a Google Pay payment button after confirmation of the viewer's
 * ability to pay.
 */
function onGooglePayLoaded() {
  const paymentsClient = getGooglePaymentsClient();
  paymentsClient.isReadyToPay(getGoogleIsReadyToPayRequest())
      .then(function(response) {
        if (response.result) {
          addGooglePayButton();
          // @todo prefetch payment data to improve performance after confirming site functionality
          // prefetchGooglePaymentData();
        }
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        // show error in developer console for debugging
        console.error(err);
      });
}

/**
 * Add a Google Pay purchase button alongside an existing checkout button
 *
 * @see {@link https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/reference/request-objects#ButtonOptions|Button options}
 * @see {@link https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/guides/brand-guidelines|Google Pay brand guidelines}
 */
function addGooglePayButton() {
  const paymentsClient = getGooglePaymentsClient();
  const button =
      paymentsClient.createButton({onClick: onGooglePaymentButtonClicked});
  document.getElementById('container').appendChild(button);
}

/**
 * Provide Google Pay API with a payment amount, currency, and amount status
 *
 * @see {@link https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/reference/request-objects#TransactionInfo|TransactionInfo}
 * @returns {object} transaction info, suitable for use as transactionInfo property of PaymentDataRequest
 */
function getGoogleTransactionInfo() {
  return {
    countryCode: 'US',
    currencyCode: 'USD',
    totalPriceStatus: 'FINAL',
    // set to cart total
    totalPrice: '1.00'
  };
}

/**
 * Prefetch payment data to improve performance
 *
 * @see {@link https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/reference/client#prefetchPaymentData|prefetchPaymentData()}
 */
function prefetchGooglePaymentData() {
  const paymentDataRequest = getGooglePaymentDataRequest();
  // transactionInfo must be set but does not affect cache
  paymentDataRequest.transactionInfo = {
    totalPriceStatus: 'NOT_CURRENTLY_KNOWN',
    currencyCode: 'USD'
  };
  const paymentsClient = getGooglePaymentsClient();
  paymentsClient.prefetchPaymentData(paymentDataRequest);
}

/**
 * Show Google Pay payment sheet when Google Pay payment button is clicked
 */
function onGooglePaymentButtonClicked() {
  const paymentDataRequest = getGooglePaymentDataRequest();
  paymentDataRequest.transactionInfo = getGoogleTransactionInfo();

  const paymentsClient = getGooglePaymentsClient();
  paymentsClient.loadPaymentData(paymentDataRequest)
      .then(function(paymentData) {
        // handle the response
        processPayment(paymentData);
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        // show error in developer console for debugging
        console.error(err);
      });
}

/**
 * Process payment data returned by the Google Pay API
 *
 * @param {object} paymentData response from Google Pay API after user approves payment
 * @see {@link https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/reference/response-objects#PaymentData|PaymentData object reference}
 */
function processPayment(paymentData) {
  // show returned data in developer console for debugging
    console.log(paymentData);
  // @todo pass payment token to your gateway to process payment
  paymentToken = paymentData.paymentMethodData.tokenizationData.token;
}
```

The button does not display at all, no API or custom private/public key seems to be required for this example to show the button.

Could you help me.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible reasons for this could be because of the country associated with your Google Account.

I've updated your JSFiddle to include a `console.log` statement: https://jsfiddle.net/ge37h05t/

```js
function onGooglePayLoaded() {
  const paymentsClient = getGooglePaymentsClient();
  paymentsClient.isReadyToPay(getGoogleIsReadyToPayRequest())
      .then(function(response) {
        if (response.result) {
          addGooglePayButton();
          // @todo prefetch payment data to improve performance after confirming site functionality
          // prefetchGooglePaymentData();
        } else {
            console.log('Not ready to pay');
        }
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        // show error in developer console for debugging
        console.error(err);
      });
}
```

Can you try again with the above link and check the console output?

One way you can verify it it is country related is by creating a new Google Account in one of the [supported countries](https://support.google.com/pay/answer/9023773?hl=en) and trying again with that.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answer : jsfiddle display "Acheter avec GPAY" that fits with my Google Account origin country (France - supported)  Console returns :{
  apiVersion: 2,
  apiVersionMinor: 0,
  paymentMethodData: {
    description: "Mastercard •••• **09",
    info: { ... },
    tokenizationData: { ... },
    type: "CARD"
  }
}

No change on my website, button is not displayed, i paste all my payg.html here https://jsfiddle.net/ReXNeB/ua2r6ph5/ and  button appears with a popup.

Best Regards

Comment: So you are saying that it works with jsfiddle, but not on your site? How are you testing your HTML? Is it using `http://`/`https://` locally or `file://`? It is hard to say what the problem is without being able to reproduce it. Are you able to try and reproduce it with a tool like [glitch](https://glitch.com/) and share it?

Comment: Hello, i'm using https:// on a public html test page. Server is "managed" with Plesk : glitch is working : https://glitch.com/~polyester-thorn-raven. Best Regards.

Comment: If the same code is working on glitch but not your own server, it must be a server configuration problem. Are you able to share the URL for the test page that it isn't working on? It's hard to say what the problem is without being able to observe directly. Otherwise, check the browser console for errors and warnings. One place to start would be response headers like `Content-Security-Policy`.

Comment: I put my code on another domain, here is a test page link https://www.rexneb.ovh/TEMP/payg.html not working. I put it on another server (Standard Debian Apache & PHP, no Plex) not working anymore. I test all link with 4 different browser and from my phone with another IP. Really don't understand (EDIT : since i don't understand any javascript i am not able to debug even with console).  Best Regards

Comment: The error that you are getting is `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` because the HTML isn't valid. JSFiddle allows you to use HTML fragments for convenience, but should not be used as-is. I've included the full HTML you should be using here: https://jsfiddle.net/m9vkz3dp/

Comment: It is now working, thank you very much. Best Regards.